# Annual returns on sin stocks

Tags: equities, market-data

[Fabozzi, Ma and Oliphant (2008)](http://gyanresearch.wdfiles.com/local--files/alpha/JPM_FA_08_FABOZZI.pdf) have this very nice comparison between the return on the overall stock market and the return on sin stocks across multiple countries. They have done this for the period 1970-2007. Does anyone know where to find an updated estimate of this graph?

[image]

Comment: Footnote 13 of this paper mentions the Vice Fund (VICEX). This fund still exists, a quick look at its 10 year performance shows no outperformance vs the averages. But the issue needs to be investigated more carefully for the full 2007-2023 period.

Comment: And I that would not give the break down by country either.